# NodeJS, Express and JSON API Response Time

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express, nginx

I have create a simple express api to handle JSON data on my webapp.

Even if the app is on the same server, the response times are always on 100ms range, the actual data fetching is under 5ms;

Here is the data fetching zone :

```
export function getData(params) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!params.take || params.take > 30 && isBrowser) {
      params.take = 30;
    }
   console.time("API QUERY Execute");
       {Data Fetching Goes here}
    console.timeEnd("API QUERY Execute");
  });
}
```

That method takes under 5 ms to complete from console.time.

Here is the express route config

```
  app.route('/api/data').get((req, res) => {
    getData(req.query)
      .then((data) => {
        res.json(data);
      }).catch((err) => {
        res.status(400);
        res.send(err.message);
      });
  });
```

The actual Express App :

```
export default (parameters) => {
  const app = Express();
  const server = require('http').Server(app);
  let io;
  let redisCaching;
  if (process.env.ENABLE_API === 'true') {
    const Mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Redis = require('socket.io-redis');
    Mongoose.connect(config.server.mongodb.url, config.server.mongodb.options);
    Mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
      console.log('==> Connected ', config.server.mongodb.url);
    });

    io = require('socket.io')(server);
    io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
      console.log('==> Socket Connect', socket.handshake.headers.referer);
    });

    io.adapter(Redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));

    redisCaching = require('../../redis/redisCaching').redisCaching;
    redisCaching.configure(6379, config.server.hostname);
  }

  if (process.env.CORS === 'true') {
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
      next();
    });
  }

        app.route('/api/data').get((req, res) => {
        getArticles(req.query)
          .then((data) => {
            res.json(data);
          }).catch((err) => {
            res.status(400);
            res.send(err.message);
          });
      });


  app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
  });
};
```

When using tools like pingdom, it showcases 100MS

Comment: I highly doubt your `console.timeEnd(...)` is in the correct spot, unless your data fetching is synchronous, in which case your use of promises is completely unnecessary.

Comment: It actually does not matter if I am doing data fetching or not, returning res.json({}) gives the exact same results.

Comment: So you're saying `app.route('/api/data').get((req, res) => { res.json({}); });` takes 100 ms?

Comment: How are you measuring the response time, is it local machine, where and how are you located(from server), DNS? Pingdom should give you the full resource timing chart which part and how long did it take, maybe it's the first time DNS lookup?  https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/imgs/resource-timing-data.png

Comment: I saw you put `nginx` tag on this question, did you use nginx when you doing the test? What is your nginx config?